# AddNewRecord XamDataGrid

Tags: infragistics, xamdatagrid

After entering a value in the AddNewRecord row, and clicking anywhere outside the row on the XamDataGrid seems to add the row to the collection.

How do I prevent mouse click from adding a new row to the collection.

Kindly any help

Comment: Any infragistics guru(s), please share your thoughts

Comment: I would like to add the new row, only by clicking on the + icon for AddNewRecord

Comment: I would sincerely appreciate if anybody can help me with this

Answer (score 2):

Clicking outside of the AddNewRecord ends edit mode on the record and if there were changes they are committed at that time which means the new record is added.  If you were looking to only allow the record to be commmited when pressing the enter key and not by clicking another record in the grid, then you could use the following logic to set the mouse left button down as handled:

```
private bool editingAddNewRecord = false;
void XamDataGrid1_EditModeEnded(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Events.EditModeEndedEventArgs e)
{
    this.editingAddNewRecord = false;
}

void XamDataGrid1_EditModeStarted(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Events.EditModeStartedEventArgs e)
{
    this.editingAddNewRecord = e.Cell.Record.IsAddRecord;
}

void XamDataGrid1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (editingAddNewRecord)
    {
        DataRecordPresenter drp = Infragistics.Windows.Utilities.GetAncestorFromType(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject, typeof(DataRecordPresenter), true) as DataRecordPresenter;
        if (!(drp != null && drp.IsAddRecord))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer @alhalama!

I noticed though that you don't handle the right mouse button down, and even when we do your solution doesn't work to support it. Also, with your solution I wasn't able to edit any other cells until I had hit Enter or Escape on the Add New Row record (which might be what some people want, but not me).  Here is my modified solution that undoes changes to the Add New Record row's cell when the user clicks out of it, which also handles all mouse clicks (left, right, middle, etc.).

```
// Used to record when the user is editing a value in the Mass Edit row.
private DataRecord _addRecordCellBeingEdited = null;

private void XamDataGrid1_EditModeStarted(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Events.EditModeStartedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cell.Record.IsAddRecord)
        _addRecordCellBeingEdited = e.Cell.Record;
}

private void XamDataGrid1_EditModeEnded(object sender, Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Events.EditModeEndedEventArgs e)
{
    _addRecordCellBeingEdited = null;
}

private void XamDataGrid1_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (_addRecordCellBeingEdited != null)
    {
        DataRecordPresenter drp = Infragistics.Windows.Utilities.GetAncestorFromType(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject, typeof(DataRecordPresenter), true) as DataRecordPresenter;
        if (!(drp != null && drp.IsAddRecord))
        {
            _addRecordCellBeingEdited.CancelUpdate();
        }
    }  
}
```